# Why is there no [spi] tag?

Tags: discussion

There are tags for [i2c](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/i2c) and [1-wire](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/1-wire), but there's no tag for [spi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spi). Why not?

There are something like 200 questions already on the site that could be classified using such a tag. Instead, they have tags like [gpio](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gpio), [driver](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/driver), [hardware](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hardware) and [peripherals](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/peripherals).

Is there any objection to creating such a tag and using it to start tagging questions?

Comment: I have no objection, but give me a couple of example questions so I can double check and if needed create the tag

Comment: Just go to the questions page and enter "spi" into the search box. Virtually all of the results are about using a SPI bus, either bit-banged or using the hardware SPI controller.

Comment: Kind of a zany oversight!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created the tag for you since you do not have enough reputation.

Comment: Much appreciated!